# ASP.NET MVC create a new table for each new ID that is in a sql table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to create a table for each "site" that I have in my "sites" database table. Hopefully this question makes more sense as I explain.

Currently, I have a view page that looks like this

```
<table>
   @foreach (var row in Model.SecondTital)
        {
            <tr style="font-size: 20px">
                @foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                    <th align="center" colspan="7" width="100%">
                        <h1>@cell </h1>
                    </th>
                }
            </tr>
        }

        <tr style="color:black">
            @foreach (var col in Model.OffReportColumns)
            {
                <th>@col</th>
            }
        </tr>

        @foreach (var row in Model.OffReportRows)
        {
            <tr style="color:black">
                @foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                    <td>@cell</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }

        @foreach (var row in Model.OffReporTotal)
        {
            <tr style="font-size: 20px">
                @foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                    <td>@cell</td>
                }
            </tr>

        }
    </table>
```

And this table is populated through my controller method that looks like this

```
            model.OffReportColumns = new List<string>()
            {
                s.Name,
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost",
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost (With labour)"
            };
            model.OffReportRows = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Parts",
                    "",
                    "",
                    opartcost.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    opartcost.ToString("C2")
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "600000 series",
                    opc6.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "600000 series",
                    opc6.ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "700000 series",
                    opc7.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "700000 series",
                    opc7.ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "800000 series",
                    opc8.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "800000 series",
                    opc8.ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Tools",
                    "",
                    "",
                    otools.ToString("C2"),
                     "",
                     "",
                    otools.ToString("C2"),

                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "900000 series",
                    opc9.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "900000 series",
                    opc9.ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "Other",
                    opco.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "Other",
                    opco.ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Components",
                    "",
                    "",
                    ocompcost.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    locompcost.ToString("C2")
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Items",
                    "",
                    "",
                    oitemcost.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    loitemcost.ToString("C2")
                },
            };

            }
```

I have 5 "site" locations that I want this table to be created for and I obviously don't want to recreate that table 5 times and cause a mess. I know a loop is the way to do it but I'm just stuck on how to do it right now. At first I did

```
foreach (Site s in db.Sites)
```

But that will just create a table for the last ID that is cycled through. So how can I make it create a table for all of them and not just the last ID in the list?